# How to get euler angles for object from solvepnp output?

Tags: python, objects, 3d-view

From opencv's solvepnp, I get the rotation vector and translation vector. How do I get the euler angles so that I can rotate the object at the origin so that when I render the camera at the default position, I get the same render as in the image I used for solvepnp.